# Supervised learning by creating own labels

Tags: machine-learning

**Scenario** - I have data that does not have labels but I can create a function to label the data based on behavior and deploy the model so I don't have to keep labeling the data. Is this considered machine learning?

**Objective**: classify accounts with Volume spikes based on high medium low labels to deploy on big data (trillions of lines of data)

**Data**: the data I have includes the following attributes:
Account, Time, Date, Volume amount.

**Method**:

1. Create a new feature column called "spike" and create a pandas function to ID a spike greater than 5. Is this feature engineering?
2. Next I create my label column and classify it as low medium or high spike.
3. Next I Train a machine learning classifier and deploy it to label future accounts with similar patterns in big data.

Thoughts on this process? Is this approach correct for Machine learning?

Comment: Funny enough, recently, a bunch of papers have been treating this scenario as self supervision...

Answer (score 1):

**1st question:**
If your algorithm takes the decision, that is, put a label in a sample, based on the set of samples that you have, I'd say it's a machine learning algorithm. But if you design a code that takes into account your experience regarding the data, I think it's not an ML method. In brief, ML look at the data to get patterns and insights from them. I don't know why you're doing that, but is it need to be an ML algorithm? Sometimes you can solve the problem in a very simple way, without using ML.

**2nd question:** I'm afraid not. Select your data attributes (ex: Account, Time, Date, Volume amount), checking their correlations, try to figure out if you have a dominant one, etc. This process is pre ML. The feature engineering will select what are the best features to present to our algorithm in order to perform the classification (in your case)

**3rd question:** I think it's fair enough to start playing with some ML algorithms, such as KNN, SVM, NNs, Decision Tree, etc.